# Add file name to image on Photoshop with JS Script

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I would like to add the filename to a image using Photoshop

Example file name

> image 123-back.jpg
>   image 123-front.jpg

I would like the to remove the -back and -front from the name added to the image

So far I can add the file name but cannot remove the -back and -front

This is the code I have so far

```
// this script is a variation of the script addTimeStamp.js that is installed with PH7

if ( documents.length > 0 )
{
    var originalDialogMode = app.displayDialogs;
    app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR;
    var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
    preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    try
    {
        var docRef = activeDocument;

        // Now create a text layer at the front
        var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
        myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
        myLayerRef.name = "Filename";

        var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

        // strip the extension off
        var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
        if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
            fileNameNoExtension.length--;
        }
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");

        myTextRef.contents = '*' + fileNameNoExtension +'*';

        // Set the position of the text  percentages from left first, then from top
        myTextRef.position = new Array( docRef.width / 2.5, docRef.height / 6 );
        myTextRef.size = 15.76;
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        // An error occurred. Restore ruler units, then propagate the error back
        // to the user
        preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
        app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
        throw e;
    }

    // Everything went Ok. Restore ruler units
    preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
    app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
}
else
{
    alert( "You must have a document open to add the filename!" );
}
```

Comment: `fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.replace("-back", "");` should work (what is unclear to me is if "image 123-back.jpg image 123-front.jpg" is one filename or two)

Answer (score 0):

PhotoShop's implementation of JavaScript supports the String `replace()` method. This can be utilized to achieve your requirement.

---

**1) Example of using `replace()`**

The following code snippet shows how the `replace()` method works.

```js
var string1 = "image 123-front"
var result1 = string1.replace("-front", "");
// --> The value for result1 equals: "image 123"

var string2 = "image 123-back"
var result2 = string2.replace("-back", "");
// --> The value for result2 equals: "image 123"
```

---

**2) Example of using `replace()` with a Regular Expression**

A [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can also be specified for the string(s) to match as follows:

```
var string3 = "image XYZ-front 123-back"
var result3 = string3.replace(/-(front|back)/g, "");
// --> The value for result3 equals: "image XYZ 123"
```

The regular expression part `/-(front|back)/g` matches both `-front` and `-back`.

Further explanation of this Regular Expression can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/zhIMOZ/1/).

---

**3) Implementing `replace()` in your script**

For clarity your script can be revised as follows. It utilizes the solution explained in example two above:

```js
if ( documents.length > 0 )
{
    var originalDialogMode = app.displayDialogs;
    app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR;
    var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
    preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    try
    {
        var docRef = activeDocument;

        // Now create a text layer at the front
        var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
        myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
        myLayerRef.name = "Filename";

        var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

        // strip the extension off
        var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
        if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
            fileNameNoExtension.length--;
        }
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");

        // Remove -front and -back from filename
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.replace(/-(front|back)/g, "");

        myTextRef.contents = '*' + fileNameNoExtension +'*';

        // Set the position of the text  percentages from left first, then from top
        myTextRef.position = new Array( docRef.width / 2.5, docRef.height / 6 );
        myTextRef.size = 15.76;
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        // An error occurred. Restore ruler units, then propagate the error back
        // to the user
        preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
        app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
        throw e;
    }

    // Everything went Ok. Restore ruler units
    preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
    app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
}
else
{
    alert( "You must have a document open to add the filename!" );
}
```

**Note**: Starting at line no. 27 the following snippet was added only:

```
// Remove -front and -back from filename
fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.replace(/-(front|back)/g, "");
```